# C# regex find and remove text after a string matched

Tags: c#, regex, string, text

I want to find and remove everything after the matched string in the text and replace it with a text, I am new to regex

```
From: Tom novy <AJames@onmicrosoft.com>
To: "mithrandir@wttom.onmicrosoft.com"
From: David Cusack <AJames@onmicrosoft.com>
```

should be:

```
From: "redacted"
To: "mithrandir@wttom.onmicrosoft.com"
From: "redacted"
```

I have a regex that replaces after a character :

```
var regex = new Regex(@":(.*)");
var newText  = regex.Replace(testString1, "");
```

How to have same regex to find "From:" only and replace everything after it (but on same line) to From: "redacted".

Comment: You have `:` in the text, why do you use `;` in the regex?

Comment: How are you getting these string? Is it predictable? Regex seems like overkill to me.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb the string comes can be different

Comment: `Regex.Replace(s, "(From:).*", "${1}<newcontents>")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew updated ; to :

Comment: Do you want to match the word followed with `:`  at the start of the string? Try `Regex.Replace(s, @"^(\w+:)[^\r\n]*", "$1 \"redacted\"")`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to match `From: ` only, so the word From followed by :

Comment: You do not need to match From:, it is already a known string. Both my suggestions do what you need. See http://ideone.com/B2nsTW

Comment: Updated http://ideone.com/B2nsTW

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew put it as an answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
Regex.Replace(s, "(From:).*", "$1 \"redacted\"")
```

Or, combining with `To:`,

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"\b((?:From|To):).*", "$1 \"redacted\"")
```

Here,

- `\b` - word boundary
- `((?:From|To):)` - Capturing group 1: either `From` or `To`, then `:`
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars, other than linebreak chars, as many as possible.

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/B2nsTW)

```
var s = "From: Tom novy <AJames@onmicrosoft.com>\nTo: \"mithrandir@wttom.onmicrosoft.com\"\nFrom: David Cusack <AJames@onmicrosoft.com>";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, "(From:).*", "$1 \"redacted\""));
```

Output:

```
From: "redacted"
To: "mithrandir@wttom.onmicrosoft.com"
From: "redacted"
```

Note that `(From:).*` matches and captures `From:` into Group 1 and the `$1` backreference is putting this value back into the result when replacing.

**NOTE**: `.` in a .NET regex matches CR symbol, too, so if you plan to only replace up to a CRLF ending, you need to replace `.` in the regex with `[^\r\n]`.

Also, if `From:` should only be matched when at the start of a *line*, you need prepend it with the `^` anchor and compile the regex with `RegexOptions.Multiline` modifier, or `(?m)` inline modifier, `"(?m)^(From:)[^\r\n]*"`.

Comment: Cool, as as other option, wonder is it possible to combine From: and To: together in expression, so it finds From: and To:...

Comment: thats a perfect example explaining everything in detail, should help other people with similar patterns

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that we might not want regular expressions here, yet if I would be wrong, maybe we would start with these expressions,

```
([a-z]+:)(.*?)([a-z]+:)(.*)
(From:)(.*?)(To:)(.*)
(From:)(.*?)([a-z]+:)(.*)
```

and we would replace with,

```
\1 "redacted"\n\3 "redacted"
```

#### [Please see the demo here for explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/5EcAoG/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"([a-z]+:)(.*?)([a-z]+:)(.*)";
        string substitution = @"\1 ""redacted""\n\3 ""redacted""";
        string input = @"From: Tom novy <AJames@onmicrosoft.com>
To: ""mithrandir@wttom.onmicrosoft.com""";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```

Comment: And how to find only From: ?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Regex.Replace("From: Tom", @"From\:.*", "From: redacted")
```

Comment: Why escape a colon?

Comment: i put an escape in front of pretty much any non alphanumeric char. gives you confidence in times of doubt :)

Comment: You almost never need to escape a colon in a regex pattern. You never need to escape it in a .NET regex.

Comment: ok, i do not know all special chars. what i ment by confidence is, that everyone, including myself, who reads this, wont have to ask himself the question if this is a special char or not. since there is no problem in escaping it, i just do it whenever im not sure. it doesnt hurt.

Comment: It would hurt if you use it in JS with the HTML5 pattern, or when compiling JS RegExp object with a `u` modifier. You won't have issues in C#, true.